# Left outer join on three tables

Tags: oracle, outer-join

I need to use left outer join on three table. Example I have three table called A,B and C. I want result like 
A left outer join ( B left outer join c).
What is the best way to do it.

I have written something like this.

```
select * from A,B,C where A.column_a=B.column_a(+) and B.column_b=C.column_b(+);
```

Comment: Why not use the `left outer join` syntax instead of the Oracle-specific `(+)`, since you seem to know how to express it like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

depending on how the tables are related (which is not entirely clear from your question),

```
 select * 
 from A
    left join B on b.column_a = a.column_a
    left join C on c.column_b = b.column_b
```

or,

```
 select * 
 from A
    left join (B left join C on c.column_b = b.column_b)
        on b.column_a = a.column_a
```